What is the Differential 4D Solid Angle?
How would I go about finding the differential 4D solid angle on a 3-sphere?
I want to define it using hyperspherical coordinates using three angles $ψ ∈ [0, π)$, $θ ∈ [0, π)$, and $φ ∈ [0, 2π)$ and a radius of $1$.
The differential solid angle for a 2-sphere is provided here:

What is the equivalent for hyperspherical coordinates on a 3-sphere?

What have you tried? Do you understand how solid angle is defined in general?
